# What is the probability that the first 2 balls are green given that the third ball is red (without replacing them)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

If in a bag there are 6 red balls and 10 green balls and 3 balls are drawn at random then what is the probability that the first 2 balls are green given that the third ball is red (without replacing them)?
Please have a look at what I did..
And I am getting answer as $42.8$%
(Correct me if wrong)

> [Image-1](https://photos.app.goo.gl/aGWRWYC3zn8YHWsY9)
>   [Image-2](https://photos.app.goo.gl/u1w7d9Y5aTowikHVA)

Comment: One can "rearrange the combinatorial tree", so that the first ball is known to be red, and we are asking for the probability that after this known first ball we further extract two green balls. Which is $$\frac{\binom{10}2}{\binom{15}2}=\frac {10\cdot 9/2}{15\cdot 14/2}=\frac 37\ .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the third is red, we may as well consider the  first two draws from a population of $5$ red and $10$ green.  They are both green with probability $$\frac {10}{15}\times \frac 9{14}=\frac 37=.\overline {428571}$$  confirming your result.

Your method looks correct but needlessly complex.  Once you know that the third draw is red, we have $5$ reds and $10$ greens left to distribute amongst $15$ slots.  Each ball is equally likely to wind up in any of the available slots, hence the calculation given above.

Comment: Okay I got the logic...